# PDFKit and new WKHTMLTOPDF binaries

Tags: ruby, report, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

According to [PDFkit Documentation](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) it could handle any wkhtml options. And that's the cool thing about it. But now with WKHTMLTOPDF-0.10.0 and higher according to it's [documentation](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html) accepts

- Multiple Html Documents
- Page, Cover, Table Of Contents parts - Cover and TOC does not take common footers and headers.

How to deal with those inside pdfkit?

because page is not that is called like

`wkhtmltopdf --page my.html`

---

it is

---

`wkhtmltopdf cover some.html page my.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by making a rewrite of pdfkit to work with new wkhtmltopdf binaries - check out http://github.com/prikha/pdfkit